# how to print the program which i am writing using FileReader class

Tags: java

I want to print the source code of current program(the program which is running)on the console using File reader?How to do it?
i.e using java.io.FileReader Class

Comment: Are you trying to write a [Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))?

Comment: To be more on-topic: You're problem is not reading the file, but determining what source file is the one corresponding to the compiled class file that is currently executed, right? If yes, you might want to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Do you have the .java and the .class files on the same computer ? If yes: Do you know the path to the workspace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see to do that is to have your `FileReader` object open the .java file from your workspace, loop through and print out each line.

EDIT: adding rough outline.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test {
    public void printMe() {
        try {
            String classname = Test.class.toString();
            // This gets the full class name, including package
            classname=  classname.replace("class ", "");
            classname= classname.replace(".", "/");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<path_to_workspace/project_name/source_folder> + classname + ".java"));

        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line=br.readLine();
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, this will only work in a workspace. You cannot print the source code of a complied java class inside a jar, as the source is compiled and thus not human-readable.

Comment: how to give path of the current file can you explain it elaborately

Comment: I'll give a rough outline in my answer.